# RUNAS Error (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, runas

I'm trying the below command

```
runas /user:\\(domain)\(myusername) C:\Users\user\compress.bat
```

I then input the password, but I get the following error -

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to acquire user password
```

What am I doing wrong?

- Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the slashes before the domain.

You want this:
runas /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME C:\Users\user\compress.bat